# MCP1630 Spice model

Tags: ltspice, spice, pspice

Does anyone knows where I can find MCP1630 spice model ? I realy need it to complete my project and microchip does not provide the spice model of this device.
On my behalf, I do not master SPICE to write the required model, can anyone do it for me ?

Comment: Microchip provides simulation information. https://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/producttc.aspx?product=AnalogSimMCP1630

Comment: can this extension (.sxsch) be run in proteus or multisim ? I mean can we create a wizard or a new component with this extension ? beceause I see it for the first time. Does microchip have a specila analog simulator ?

Comment: I do not know; try downloading them and reading the documentation.

Comment: I have already done this, We can not using in another simulator, we can only run it with SIMetrix, a software developped to simulate circuits with that kind of extension, thank you anyway